# ¿Por qué mi descarga no se inicia?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

He estado diseñando una aplicación android basada en webview. Pero recientemente he tenido un problema al iniciar una descarga, y es que la descarga no se inicia, aquí va parte de mi código:

- El listener

  ```
  mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {

      @Override
      public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength) {
          //permisos
          if (deseaDescargar()){


              if (checkGrantedPermission()){
                  //descarga directa
                  Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                          "Descargando", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  final DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                  request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                  request.setMimeType(mimetype);
                  // cookie
                  String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                  request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                  //cookie
                  request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                  request.setDescription("Descargando");
                  request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
                  request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                  request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                  request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype));
                  final DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

                  new Thread("Browser download"){
                      public void run() {
                          dm.enqueue(request);
                      }
                  }.start();

              }else if(checkGrantedPermission() == false) {
                  Toast.makeText(Main.this,
                          "Permiso necesario para poder realizar esta accion ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
          }

          }

  });
  ```
- Las funciones

  ```
     public boolean checkGrantedPermission(){
  int OS = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
  final boolean[] permiso = new boolean[1];
  if(OS >= 23 ){
      int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Main.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
      if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
          permiso[0] = true;

      }else {
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Main.this,
                  new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                  REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
      }
  }else {
      permiso[0] = true;
  }
  return permiso[0];

  }
  public boolean deseaDescargar() {
  final boolean[] download = new boolean[1];
  new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this)
          .setTitle("Descargar?")
          .setPositiveButton("Si",
                  new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                          download[0] = true;


                      }
                  })
          .setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                  dialog.cancel();
              }
          }).show();
  return download[0];
  }
  ```

Pd. El Dialogo de descarga se muesta pero no hace nada, y al quitarlo la descarga funciona, sin embargo no encuentro el error :(

Comment: Dices que una vez cierras el diálogo la descarga funciona?

Comment: Al quitar el dialogo del codigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucho, el problema es que esta mal estructurado el código, cuando llamas el dialogo, este se muestra y en ese instante después de crear el dialogo, se obtiene un valor boolean `false`, es por esto que no realiza la descarga.

```
  if (deseaDescargar()){

            if (checkGrantedPermission()){
            ...
```

Te recomiendo llames la descarga al momento de realizar el click en el botón "Si", puedes meter el código de la descarga en un método y llamar este método dentro de `onClick()` de tu dialogo:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(Main.this)
        .setTitle("Descargar?")
        .setPositiveButton("Si",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                     //* Llamar descarga

                    }
                })

 ...
 ...
```